# Is there a way to know the view type from PHP code?

Tags: 7, views

Is there a way to know the view type (page or block) from PHP code?

```
if (views type is block) {
  echo "This is a block view.";
}
elseif (views type is page) {
  echo "This is a page view.";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Views module, the exact term for what you're talking about is *display handler*.

If you have a view object, you can find the current object for the display handler at `$view->display_handler`. The class for that object is returned by  `get_class($view->display_handler)`, which would return a string like `'views_plugin_display_page'`, for example.

When checking the class of an object, you can use `instanceof`, as in the following code.

```php
if ($view->display_handler instanceof views_plugin_display_page) {
  // Your code
}
```